# What hooks to use for Wordpress POST request.

Tags: wordpress, post, action

There seems to be two hooks to handle POST request in Wordpress. The first is the `admin-post` hook. And the second is the `admin_action_{$_REQUEST[‘action’]}` hook.

Are they suitable for different occasions? Is one preferable over the other?

Comment: I find this question a little strange. There are many, many ways that WordPress handles a HTTP POST request. The two hooks you refer to are from an entry point to WordPress that is not frequently used, AFAIK. May I ask why it seems to you that these are the only two hooks that WordPress uses to handle POST request.

Comment: Its the two suggestion I find when googling. Wort mentioning is that am looking for hooks for handling custom created POST actions for a plugin. For example save settingss on a settings page (I dont use the settings API), or remove a piece of data on a custom admin page.

Comment: I misunderstood your question as it seem to refer to all POST requests in WordPress. For custom POST requests from plugins those hooks can be used but I think it is more common to use the AJAX API.

Answer (score 1):

The 'admin_post_' . $_REQUEST['action'] action hooks are used to handle forms e.g.,

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) ); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="your_action">
    ...
</form>
```

The 'admin_action_' . $_REQUEST['action'] action hooks are used to handle actions on certain admin urls (the php files that include wp-admin/admin.php), e.g.,

```
'<a href="' . admin_url( "admin.php?action=your_action&..." ) . '">...</a>
'<a href="' . admin_url( "edit.php?action=your_action&..." ) . '">...</a>
'<a href="' . admin_url( "post.php?action=your_action&..." ) . '">...</a>
```

I don't think either of these hooks are frequently used. At least not in the plugins that I am using. Usually, the action is handled later by the called php file, e.g. wp-admin/edit.php, wp-admin.post.php, ...